# ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

[image: Error Screen2]  [image: Error Screen1]
while publishing app on web getting error called: check your log or contact the app auther.please find above image links

> ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.

if anyone can help me to resolve this error I'd be grateful.

Comment: If you are publishing as a `shiny` package like myself, this may be because you cannot install the app itself (e.g. myapp::launch_app). An option is to use `golem` if you prefer.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple reasons for this error. Rstudio has provided multiple reasons (link below) but most common are:

1. Environment variables not the same in shiny web vs. local (make sure working directory is set to ~/, start a new rsession and run only the ui.R, server.R or app.R and see if you can preview in local before publishing.)
2. Update libraries to latest versions and hopefully you are not using the libraries that are not yet available in CRAN.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-

Comment: This worked for me - in my case, I did not specify all required libraries in the app when publishing. There were existing libraries loaded. Restarting R soon highlighted the problem. Thanks