# Why shiny works localy not on the server

Tags: r, shiny

I have following app that works fine when I start it locally but when deploying on the shiny server I get an error. The ggplot object `output$plot1` is not visible and the error is `An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.`

The app is here https://mateuszskog.shinyapps.io/MALval/

The app code is as follow

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(rpivotTable)
library(DT)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("DMS data Viewer"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
              accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
    #tags$hr(),

    checkboxInput('header', label = "Header", TRUE),

    fluidRow(
      column(4,radioButtons("xaxisGrp","X-Axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2"))),
      column(4,radioButtons("yaxisGrp","Y-axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2")))
      #column(4,selectInput("colpointsGrp","Grouping:", c("1"="1","2"="2")))
    ),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
    radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                 c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'"'),
    radioButtons('shower', 'Show first 10 rows',
                 c(Show=10,
                   DoNotShow=FALSE
                 )),
    uiOutput("choose_columns")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Data", tableOutput('contents1')),
      tabPanel("Plots",plotOutput("plot1"), plotOutput("plotDist")),
      tabPanel("Descriptive summary", verbatimTextOutput("Descripsummary")),
      tabPanel("Pivot Table", rpivotTableOutput("OverallPivot"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dsnames <- c()

  data_set <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(mtcars)

    data_set<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, 
                       sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote, na.string = ".")
    data_set
  })

  output$contents1 <- renderTable({head(data_set(), input$shower)}) #n = input$shower

  observe({
    dsnames <- names(data_set())
    cb_options <- list()
    cb_options[ dsnames] <- dsnames
    updateRadioButtons(session, "xaxisGrp",
                       label = "X-Axis",
                       choices = cb_options,
                       selected = "")
    updateRadioButtons(session, "yaxisGrp",
                       label = "Y-Axis",
                       choices = cb_options,
                       selected = "")
    updateSelectInput(session, "colpointsGrp", label = "Color-Points",
                      choices = cb_options,
                      selected = "")
  })

  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })

  output$plot1 = renderPlot(
    {
      df <- data_set()
      gp <- NULL
      if (!is.null(df)){
        xv <- input$xaxisGrp
        yv <- input$yaxisGrp
        #col <- input$colpointsGrp
        if (!is.null(xv) & !is.null(yv) ){ #n = input$shower
          if (sum(xv %in% names(df))>0){ # supress error when changing files
            mdf <- df %>% select(input$xaxisGrp, input$yaxisGrp) #, input$colpointsGrp
            gp <- ggplot(data=mdf) + 
              geom_point(aes_string(x=input$xaxisGrp,y=input$yaxisGrp)) + #, color=input$colpointsGrp)
              ylab(input$yaxisGrp)
          }
        }
      }
      return(gp)
    }
  )

  output$plotDist = renderPlot(
    {
      df <- data_set()
      gp <- NULL
      if (!is.null(df)){
        xv <- input$xaxisGrp

        if (!is.null(xv)){
          if (sum(xv %in% names(df))>0){ # supress error when changing files
            mdf <- melt(df,id.vars=xv)
            gp <- ggplot(data=mdf) + 
              geom_density(aes_string(x=xv))
          }
        }
      }
      return(gp)
    }
  )

  output$OverallPivot <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(data = data_set())
  })


  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data_set())       
  })


  output$Descripsummary <- renderPrint({
    summary(data_set())
  })


  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()
    colnames <- names(contents)
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  }) 
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

> > sessionInfo() R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit) Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build
> >     9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1](https://mateuszskog.shinyapps.io/MALval/) LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252    [3] LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252
>   LC_NUMERIC=C                    [5] LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1](https://mateuszskog.shinyapps.io/MALval/) stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1](https://mateuszskog.shinyapps.io/MALval/) DT_0.7               rpivotTable_0.3.0
>   data.table_1.11.8    leaflet_2.0.2        [5] shinydashboard_0.7.1
>   bindrcpp_0.2.2       dplyr_0.7.8          shiny_1.2.0          [9]
>   ggplot2_3.1.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1](https://mateuszskog.shinyapps.io/MALval/) reshape2_1.4.3
>   jsonlite_1.5      rstudioapi_0.8    magrittr_1.5      gtable_0.2.0
>   [6] tidyr_0.8.2       hms_0.4.2         utf8_1.1.4        xml2_1.2.0
>   pillar_1.3.0      [11] htmltools_0.3.6   forcats_0.3.0
>   stringr_1.3.1     haven_2.0.0       later_0.7.5       [16] broom_0.5.0
>   cellranger_1.1.0  lattice_0.20-35   htmlwidgets_1.3   tidyselect_0.2.5
>   [21] plyr_1.8.4        lubridate_1.7.4   mime_0.6
>   pkgconfig_2.0.2   R6_2.3.0          [26] digest_0.6.18
>   colorspace_1.3-2  stringi_1.2.4     crosstalk_1.0.0   yaml_2.2.0
>   [31] lazyeval_0.2.1    labeling_0.3      fansi_0.4.0
>   gdata_2.18.0      tibble_1.4.2      [36] httr_1.3.1
>   compiler_3.5.1    bindr_0.1.1       cli_1.0.1         withr_2.1.2
>   [41] backports_1.1.2   gmodels_2.18.1    xtable_1.8-3
>   munsell_0.5.0     modelr_0.1.2      [46] Rcpp_1.0.0
>   readxl_1.1.0      sourcetools_0.1.7 tidyverse_1.2.1   MASS_7.3-50
>   [51] openssl_1.1       assertthat_0.2.0  readr_1.1.1
>   gtools_3.8.1      tools_3.5.1       [56] httpuv_1.4.5
>   scales_1.0.0      crayon_1.3.4      glue_1.3.0        purrr_0.2.5
>   [61] rlang_0.3.0.1     nlme_3.1-137      rvest_0.3.2
>   promises_1.0.1    rsconnect_0.8.11  [66] grid_3.5.1

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47727806/680068

Comment: I do not agree @zx8754, my question is quite specific I guess. Code available, app available.

Comment: Notice I said "Related", just in case it helped, you could comment, and I would only then close it. Good practice to add links to other similar posts that you have researched, to keep related posts linked.

Comment: I have tried your code and it is running in local with my CSV.... only thing can you add library(dplyr) in your code and redeploy it??...it works in mine...

Comment: including `dplyr` solved the problem, thanks @Subhasish1315